# Discard queued data in winsock internal buffers for TCP connections

Tags: sockets, winapi, tcp, buffer, winsock

Following problem applies to a `winsock` TCP socket connection.

Is there a way to **discard** any already **sent** but queued internal winsock buffers so that it will not be sent if the wire quality is getting better again (i.e. noisy WLAN connection). The reason for **not** sending the data is that it make no sense to send old video live stream frames, all old frames should be discarded so that only the newest will be sent.

Will the buffers be discarded is SO_SNDBUF is set to zero?

**Edit:** I know UDP could be the better option here, but there are some reasons that argued against using UDP:

- Assembling of packets
- Ordering of packets
- Designing decisions

Especially the ordering requires additional buffering on application side. The approach discarding any packets with smaller frame number than the already processed could be an option, but this could lead to the situation where a large amount of the frames will be discarded.

Comment: I don't think you even can set `SO_SNDBUF` to zero, and I'd be surprised, in fact astonished, if you could set it smaller than whatever data is already in there.

Comment: That's my comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not without going into kernel space.  How would you even address it?  Data from all processes are intermixed at this point, so it would be difficult to say what to send and what not to.  Your process would at least have to be privileged to do anything like this even if some sort of API existed.

Also, why are you sending video TCP?  If you're worried about performance (as in not getting stuck behind dealing with old frames), UDP would likely be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

No, once you've handed the data down to the operating system, it owns it and will make its best effort in delivering it to the other end. You can't change or remove that data.

What you possibly can do is lower the send buffer size, such that the operating system doesn't queue as much data - and rather queue the data yourself in your application. You control the queue in the application, and can discard that data. Some fine tuning is needed, as a too low send buffer can lower the throughput.